# replacing a voltage regulator on a snow machine with a tansistor of some sort?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a 2002 Grand Touring 600 se.  For some odd reason there are no aftermarket manufactures who producing voltage regulators for my year and model of snowmachine.  There are other models that have the same voltage regulator, but noone is selling any....My final option is to find a way to by-pass or look for an alternate solution....possibly a tansistor???

I don't know much about electrical...need help

Comment: You cannot replace regulator by transistor. If you don't know what are you doing, then don't do it. Find somebody who knows how regulator works and what parameters are in play.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do in this case (in my opinion) is to find out which voltage regulator is being used, then look up its specs (a quick google search of the part number should do it) then you can find one with the same output voltage which closely match the same specs as your one and fit that instead.

That should be the best and easiest way

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just stick a transistor in there!

We need to know specs, like, the input voltage range & current, and, the output voltage & current. This will greatly affect advice on what kind of substitute voltage regulator to use.

You may want to see if there's one for this model being sold on one of the commercial internet sales sites.